# Django FormView and pagination

Tags: django, django-views

I am using django's FormView to return set of objects if form is valid.
My view function is as such:

```
class IdeaView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contributor/browse_photo.html'

    def get_form_class(self):
        return ContributorSearchForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        filter_dict = {}
        for key, value in cleaned_data.iteritems():
            if key == 'colour' and cleaned_data['colour']:
                filter_dict['colour_tag1'] = cleaned_data['colour']

            if key == 'style' and cleaned_data['style']:
                filter_dict['style_tag1'] = cleaned_data['style']

            if key == 'material_type' and cleaned_data['material_type']:
                filter_dict['material'] = cleaned_data['material_type']

            if key == 'space' and cleaned_data['space']:
                filter_dict['space_tag1'] = cleaned_data['space']

            if key == 'sub_category' and cleaned_data['sub_category']:
                filter_dict['space_sub_tag1'] = cleaned_data['sub_category']

        contrib_images = ContributorImage.objects.filter(**filter_dict)
        form = self.get_form_class()
        form = form(initial=cleaned_data)

        return render_to_response('contributor/browse_photo.html', 
            {'form':form,
            'contrib_obj':contrib_images },
            context_instance=RequestContext(self.request)
            )
```

I want to paginate on contrib_images.My problem is i cant figure out how to fit pagination in this scheme of things?

Comment: What is it that you want to paginate? `contrib_images`? Because the problem is that pagination works via GET requests and the `?page=...` parameter. And the FormViews work with POST if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @EWit yes i want paginate on contrib_images, i agree that formview works on post and paginator on get .. is there any way out !

Comment: What is the HTML like? Because you could could do the paginator logic manually. I.e. extract page_number from `self.request.POST.get('page',1)` and then add a button for prev/next to the form and just repost it every time the user wants to change pages. Or you can try to get the form to use GET params but I'm not sure the classes allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a few classes that help you manage paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links. These classes live in `django/core/paginator.py`

[Link to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/#module-django.core.paginator)