# Django Formview pagination

Tags: django, pagination

Is it possible to implement pagination in a Django Formview? If so, can someone please provide an example?

I've been able to employ pagination in ListView, but not FormView. There's been a [similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381761/django-formview-and-pagination), but the answer doesn't include a usable example, while the link to the docs is broken. I'd be grateful if someone can give me an illustrative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try subclassing `MultipleObjectMixin` [[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin)

Your view would then be something like:

```
class MyView(MultipleObjectMixin, FormView):
    # Your code
```

Comment: Gives me a `keyerror: u'object_list'`. I'm actually overriding the `get_context_data` method, and end up getting this error on `context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`